# Keyboard/configuration shortcut to switch between tabbed windows (project/window tabs, not file tabs within a project) in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ide, editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

You are now able to group separate windows/projects into one main view and switch between them by clicking the tabs. When they were separate windows, you could use 'cmd+`' to switch between them on MacOS. This no longer works in project/window tabs.

Looking for the keybindings to set this, hopefully OS-agnostic.

Comment: Merging multiple windows into a single window (i.e. having two sets of tabs) is specific to MacOS; does the standard MacOS key binding to swap windows not work? I don't run High Sierra so my MacOS doesn't do this, but on my machine swapping windows is `Cmd+Tab` not `Cmd+\``.

Comment: Good point. I'm on `10.12.6`. and `Cmd+\`` does not work. I've opted to use a plugin called `GoToWindow` as a temporary solution. `Cmd+Tab` still works to go through file tabs, and if I have multiple ST3 windows, `Cmd+\`` will scroll through each.

Comment: i'm interested in this too .. i just filed an issue here: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2740